# How to calculate speed, given potential energy and mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

A question from a CIE IGCSE Physics past paper:

[image: Potential energy]

> [A train, travelling at speed $v$, is approaching a buffer.]
>
> The train, of mass $2.5 \text{kg}$, is stopped by compressing a spring in the buffer. After the train has stopped, the energy stored in the spring is $0.48 \text{J}$. Calculate the initial speed $v$ of the train.

Combining the formula for the potential energy and the givens doesn't seem to lead us to the answer.

$P.E = mgh$

Speed doesn't fit here. But it does in:

$K.E = mv^2/2$

But then it isn't the kinetic energy. Is it?

I may be mistaking the energy given as the potential energy, when it really was supposed to be kinetic energy. Everything would then make perfect sense.

But no: the energy in question is "*stored* in spring". The very fundamental definition of potential energy is that it's stored. So, the energy given must be potential energy. Or elastic potential energy, to be accurate.

I really can't make any sense of this.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Why on earth was this downvoted? How much more should I clarify the question and my thought process? What is the issue with this?

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rodney gave you the solution, but I would like to suggest how to approach such problems. You should not be looking through all the equations you know and guess which might be applicable. That's not how physics is done. This also refers to how you pose the question (*How to calculate speed, given potential energy and mass?*). There is not one way to calculate speed from potential energy and mass. It always depends on the system you have, which should be your focus. (See below for another system which works differently.)

Instead start by reading carefully through the question and extract the relevant information from the problem first in common than translated in physicist language. Also see, if you can split the problem in different parts (typically in space or time; here in time). Try to simplify the situation as much as possible.

If you do this for the problem at hand you would end up with:

### In common language

There are basically two parts/states separated by time:

1. train moves (nothing special about the buffer)
2. train stands still; buffer is compressed

Nothing special is said about what happens during the breaking period.

### In physicist language

Here you can further simplify things eliminating not relevant information such as whether it is a train, a car or any other mass.

1. a mass $m$ moves at velocity $v$
2. the same mass was stopped by a (now compressed) spring which gained an energy $E$

Now it is time to think what you can do with the information that you are given. If you think about the real situation from your experience, all kind of things would happen: the spring would be compressed, but probably also heat generated, etc. Given that the train is not perfectly flat all of this would further complicate things. Are you expected to fully model the collision with temperature and other losses? Likely not, as you know almost nothing about the problem.

The best you can do is to remember what you know about collision problems. Depending on the type of collision you could have energy or momentum conservation or something in-between. For tackling "something in-between" you don't have enough data, obviously in the model given momentum is not conserved, because initially the train moves and then nothing moves. So your only way to provide some kind of a solution is to assume that energy is conserved, i.e. the energy before the collision (kinetic energy of the train $\frac{m}{2}v^2$) is completely converted into the energy stored in the spring (which is given). Finding the velocity from this should be easy.

---

Just an example to show that there is no unique way to calculate speed from potential energy.

As promised in the first paragraph, an example that is solved slightly differently: A massive cylinder rolling down an incline. Here you have conversion of gravitational potential energy ($mgh$) into (translational) kinetic energy ($\frac{m}{2}v^2$) **and rotational energy**. So you'd equate the potential energy not only with the kinetic energy, but with the sum of kinetic and rotational energy.

Answer (score 2):

$mgh$ is the gravitational potential energy. You want to use $\frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)^2$, which will give you the potential energy stored in the spring when compressed by an amount $\Delta x$.

Ignore that: I misread the problem. You're given the total energy stored in the spring. That stored energy in the spring came from the train's kinetic energy just before impact with the spring. So what the problem is telling you is that the train possessed $0.48\text{ J}$ of kinetic energy when it hit the spring. Knowing the mass of the train, you can solve for its speed at impact.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea such a formula existed, nor that the $mgh$ equation is limited to gravitational potential energy.

Comment: So, the kinetic energy of the train was passed on to the spring as elastic potential energy?

Comment: Yes the KE equals the stored energy in the spring when the train stops.

Comment: Ah. I get it now. It's a case of energy transfer.

Comment: You're welcome. The conservation of energy equation for this system looks like this: $\frac{1}{2}mv_{i}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)_{i}^{2} = \frac{1}{2}mv_{f}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)_{f}^{2}$, where $v_{i}$ is the speed at impact, $\Delta x_{i}$ is the spring compression at impact (zero), $v_{f}$ is the train's final speed (zer0), and $\Delta x_{f}$ is the spring's final compression. $k$ is the spring constant. But for this problem they're giving you the overall value of $\frac{1}{2}k(\Delta x)_{f}^{2}$, so you don't need to know the values of $\Delta x_{f}$ and $k$.

Comment: The key observation here is that strained matter (here a compressed spring) has potential energy (usually called "elastic potential energy" to distinguish it from "gravitational potential energy"), meaning that you can still use the infrastructure of energy conservation to address your problem.

Comment: Potential energy is often (usually?) introduced using the example of gravity.  This approach is unfortunate and has several defects, one of which you have discovered.